# PDF takes 22 seconds to download but at second execution 5 seconds (JAVA) - Why

Tags: java, pdf, ftp, apache-camel, sftp

My API REST looks like this (i am using JAVA, APACHE CAMEL):

```
http://server3343.erp.local:5464/api/rest/invoices/receipts/pdf?companyNumber=45&accountNumber=000333&documentType=FC&transactionNumber=BG534530SF
```

These parameters are completed to look for a file, in the given example i set:

```
companyNumber: 45
accountNumber: 000333
documentType: FC
transactionNumber: BG534530SF
```

The PDF file has this name:

```
45000333FCBG534530SF
```

The filename is specified and then, my code try to find it in the FTP DIRECTORY

---

The problem is that everytime time it is executed it TAKES more than **20 seconds to get the file**:
[image]

**But the second time it is executed it takes 5 seconds or less:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
  package ar.com.newsan.esb.route;
    
    import ar.com.company.camel.common.route.RestRouteBuilder;
    import ar.com.company.esb.Constants;
    import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
    import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestParamType;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    
    @Component
    public class GetReceiptsPDFRoute extends RestRouteBuilder {
    
        @Value("${timeout.FTP}")
        private Long timeoutFTP;
    
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            super.configure();
            rest(restApiPath)
                .get("/receipts/pdf?companyNumber={companyNumber}&accountNumber={accountNumber}&documentType={documentType}&transactionNumber={transactionNumber}").id("receipts PDF")
                .param().name("companyNumber").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
                .param().name("accountNumber").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
                .param().name("documentType").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
                .param().name("transactionNumber").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
                .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .produces("application/pdf")
                .to("direct:receiptsPDF");
    
            /**
             *  set name and location to look for the PDF in FTP DIRECTORY
             */
            from("direct:receiptsPDF").routeId("ReceiptsPDF")
                .setProperty("currentOperation", constant("ReceiptsPDF"))
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"ReceiptsPDF", "[Inicia ${property.currentOperation}]")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "company Number: ${header.companyNumber}")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "account Number: ${header.accountNumber}")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "document Type: ${header.documentType}")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "transaction Number: ${header.transactionNumber}")
                .doTry()
                    .choice()
                        .when(header("documentType").isEqualTo(Constants.FILE))
                            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "ReceiptsPDF","[${property.currentOperation}] Find FILE")
                            .setHeader("TARGET_DIR", simple("{{source.ebs.FILEs}}"))
                    .endChoice()
                    .otherwise()
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "ReceiptsPDF","[${property.currentOperation}] Find FILES")
                        .setHeader("TARGET_DIR", simple("{{source.ebs.FILES}}"))
                    .end()
                    .setProperty("fileName", simple("${header.companyNumber}${header.accountNumber}${header.documentType}${header.transactionNumber}.pdf"))
                    .to("direct:findPdfInFTP")
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"ReceiptsPDF", "[Ending ${property.currentOperation}]")
                .endDoTry()
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "ReceiptsPDF", "[ERROR: ${exception.message}")
            .end();
    
            /**
             *  search in FTP DIRECTORY
             */
            from("direct:findPdfInFTP").routeId("find file in ftp")
                .doTry()
                    .to("direct:searchInFTP")
                    .choice()
                        .when(simple("${body} == null"))
                            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "findPdfInFTP", "Search in processed sub-direcotries")
                            .setHeader("TARGET_DIR", simple("${header.TARGET_DIR}/Procesados"))
                            .to("direct:searchInFTP")
                    .otherwise()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"findPdfInFTP","FILE OBTAINED: ${headers.CamelFileName}")
                .endDoTry()
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "findPdfInFTP", "[ERROR: ${exception.message}")
                .end();
    
            from("direct:searchInFTP").routeId("searchInFTP")
                .doTry()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "searchInFTP","Search: {{ebs.sftp}}/${header.TARGET_DIR}/${property.fileName}")
                    .pollEnrich().simple("{{ebs.sftp}}/${header.TARGET_DIR}?password={{ebs.sftp.password}}&fileName=${property.fileName}&disconnect=true&useList=false&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true&useUserKnownHostsFile=false").timeout(timeoutFTP)
                .endDoTry()
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "searchInFTP", "[ERROR: ${exception.message}")
                .end();
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with my code? I need to find it in 5 seconds, at once.

Comment: Hey @KJ thanks for replying. I do not understand. What do you mean?. What should i do?

Comment: @KJ don't know what to do. I don't understand or why this is happening. It does not make sense to me :/